# HAPROXY multiple context based routing not working

Tags: routes, reverse-proxy, haproxy

Im having below haproxy configuration to route two urls based on context path. But during my testing found that app1 is always working fine and app2 is not working but routed to app1 itself.

Using reqirep to ignore the context path while routing to application (this is needed by my application)

From browser i will call like,

http://test.com/app1 should be routed to app1
http://test.com/app2 should be routed to app2

Any help would be appreciated?

```
frontend http_frontend
    bind *:80
    mode http
http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000
reqirep  ^([^\ :]*)\ /app1(.*) \1\ /\2
reqirep  ^([^\ :]*)\ /app2(.*) \1\ /\2
###################### ACL ###########################
 acl acl_app1 hdr_dom(host) test.com path_beg -i /app1
  use_backend acl-backend_app1 if acl_app1
###################### ACL ###########################
 acl acl_app2 hdr_dom(host) test.com path_beg -i /app2
  use_backend acl-backend_app2 if acl_app2
###################### ACL ###########################'
```

Comment: Do you have a default backend specified for this frontend? I ask, because I would not expect app1 to be working, either, since I would expect neither of these ACLs to match.  What version of HAProxy are you running?

Comment: I'm using HAProxy version of 1.8.1 and answering to your question i have backends defined but did not mention here. Also i have tried below method but it is asking for username and password though security is disabled (This is weird i'm facing when HAProxy is unable to parse acl filter ??)

             `acl acl_app hdr_dom(host) test.com
             acl msg-url-1 url_beg /app1
             acl msg-url-2 url_beg /app2          
            use_backend acl_app-backend_1 if msg-url-1 acl_app
            use_backend acl_app-backend_2 if msg-url-2 acl_app `